# Google maps json geocoding, no response in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

For whatever reason the following request gets no response from google. However if I paste the URL into the address bar it works fine. I'm not sure why this would happen. Is google filtering out requests by referrer headers?

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=3122%2C%20Australia

```
     $.ajax({
            url:'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address='+post_code+encodeURIComponent(', Australia'),
            success:function(data) {
                alert(data);
                if(data['status'] == 'OK') {
                    var location = data['results'][0]['geometry']['location'];
                    map.panTo(location['lat']+':'+location['lng']);
                    map.setZoom(8);
                }
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you may be getting blocked by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

You are trying to use the [Server-side Geocoding Web Service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/index.html) when Google Maps provides a full featured [Client-side Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Geocoding) for JavaScript. There is also a [v2 version](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/services.html), but this has been deprecated recently.

This automatically solves your same-origin problem, and in addition the request limits would be calculated per client IP address instead of of per server IP address, which can make a huge difference for a popular site.

The client-side service should be quite easy to use. Here's a very simple geocoding example using the v3 API:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
   <title>Google Maps Geocoding Demo</title> 
   <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
           type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head> 
<body> 
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
   var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

      if (geocoder) {
         geocoder.geocode({ 'address': 'Australia' }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
              console.log(results[0].geometry.location);
            } 
            else {
              console.log('No results found: ' + status);
            }
         });
      }
   </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

The above should print `(-25.274398, 133.775136)` to the console.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I got it working and came back to find you have changed it to use geometry.location. Nice work, I'm sure this will be useful to others.

Comment: Any tips on how to reverse this, I need to get a town/city from latlng values.